# Changing the legends of plot using geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very simple problem that I am struggling with, namely changing the legends of plot using geom_smooth  in ggplot2.

Here is my code:

```
p1<-    mtcars$group <- factor(mtcars$vs)
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, group=group)) +
      geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, show.legend=TRUE,aes(linetype=group), colour="black")

p1
```

[result of p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtz2x.png)

What I would like to do, is change the labels: i.e.: from "group" to "legend" and from "0" to "Experiment" and "1" to "Control". I tried to do this by addeding the labs argument and using scale_fill_discrete:

```
p2<-  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, group=group)) +
        geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, show.legend=TRUE,aes(linetype=group), colour="black")+
        labs(linetype="Legend")+
      scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Experiment", "Control"))
p2
```

The result changes the legend title, ([p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIirb.png)) but still does not change the labels. Any ideas?

EDIT:

This solves the problem, thanks for the quick replies:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, group=group)) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, show.legend=TRUE,aes(linetype=group), colour="black")+
  labs(linetype="Legend")+
  scale_linetype_discrete(labels=c("Experiment", "Control"))
```

My mistake was using `scale_fill_discrete` instead of `scale_linetype_discrete`.

Comment: use `scale_linetype_discrete()` instead of fill

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this gives the error: _Error: attempt to apply non-function_: **EDIT**: Nevermind, re-run the code, the results are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get the error if you run the code like this?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp, group=group)) +
    geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, show.legend=TRUE,aes(linetype=group), colour="black")+
    labs(linetype="Legend")+
    scale_linetype_discrete(labels=c("Experiment", "Control"))
```

I get this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nate, I've updated my code and it looks exactly like it should.